# Python - Kafka: consumer failing

Tags: python, kafka-consumer-api, kafka-producer-api

I have a simple Producer-Consumer setup: 1 producer(as a thread) and 2 consumers(as 2 processes).
The run method of producer:

```
    def run(self):
        producer = KafkaProducer(bootstrap_servers=self.bootstrap_servers, 
                                 api_version=(0, 10))
        while not self.stop_event.is_set():
           self.logger.info("Checking for new changes")
           self.check_for_new_changes(producer)
           self.logger.info("Sleeping for {minutes} 
                          minutes...".format(minutes=self.time_to_sleep / 60))
           time.sleep(self.time_to_sleep)
        producer.close()
```

Basically it checks for changes, sends messages if new changes found and then goes to sleep for 5 minutes.

The run method:

```
def run(self):
    if self.group_id:
        consumer = KafkaConsumer(bootstrap_servers=self.bootstrap_servers,
                                 consumer_timeout_ms=1000,
                                 api_version=(0, 10),
                                 group_id=self.group_id)
    else:
        consumer = KafkaConsumer(bootstrap_servers=self.bootstrap_servers,
                                 consumer_timeout_ms=1000,
                                 api_version=(0, 10))
    consumer.subscribe(['new_change'])
    while not self.stop_event.is_set():
        for msg in consumer:
            self.logger.info("New message:\n{msg}".format(msg=msg))
            self.process_new_change(json.loads(msg.value))
            if self.stop_event.is_set():
                consumer.close()
                return
    consumer.close()
```

It seems to work fine but after running for a while I get these messages in the coordinator log:

```
[2017-12-17 02:06:40,639] INFO [GroupCoordinator 0]: Member kafka-python-1.3.5-f5cdcad3-bc1a-4623-a42b-f5de5e8bded1 in group meta_data_consumer has failed, removing it from the group (kafka.coordinator.group.GroupCoordinator)
[2017-12-17 02:06:40,659] INFO [GroupCoordinator 0]: Preparing to rebalance group meta_data_consumer with old generation 15 (__consumer_offsets-6) (kafka.coordinator.group.GroupCoordinator)
[2017-12-17 02:06:40,659] INFO [GroupCoordinator 0]: Group meta_data_consumer with generation 16 is now empty (__consumer_offsets-6) (kafka.coordinator.group.GroupCoordinator)
[2017-12-17 02:06:41,784] INFO [GroupCoordinator 0]: Member kafka-python-1.3.5-bdea8ce3-922f-4ee1-9959-13341e1730f5 in group failures_consumer has failed, removing it from the group (kafka.coordinator.group.GroupCoordinator)
[2017-12-17 02:06:41,785] INFO [GroupCoordinator 0]: Preparing to rebalance group failures_consumer with old generation 9 (__consumer_offsets-35) (kafka.coordinator.group.GroupCoordinator)
[2017-12-17 02:06:41,785] INFO [GroupCoordinator 0]: Group failures_consumer with generation 10 is now empty (__consumer_offsets-35) (kafka.coordinator.group.GroupCoordinator)
```

This kills my consumers and they stop running.
I don't see any exceptions or errors in the consumer logs.

What might cause them to fail?

Comment: Is your kafka installation standalone or working with zookeeper? It seems to be an issue with rebalancing. And did this happen when you use the "consumer group" or without using it?

Comment: With zookeeper and with group_id.
I have two groups.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your `zookeeper.session.timeout.ms` is set lower than 5 minutes. Adjust that timeout from zookeeper settings. See if it still fails. If it does, then you should adjust the timeouts in kafka configs. `group.max.session.timeout.ms`, `rebalance.timeout.ms`, `heartbeat.interval.ms` should be adjusted accordingly. Your client sleeps for 5 minutes, and during that time, one of those timeout value is exceeded, and Group Coordinator tries to rebalance the consumer, thinking those consumers have failed.

Source: [Kafka Documentation](https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/)

Comment: But my producer is the one that sleeping. Should it affect the consumers?